# Security Vulnerability with using EOL version Java

Tags: java, security

Are there any security vulnerabilites with using the following version of Java on our internal intranet web server?

```
java version "1.4.2", gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)
I think this version was decommissioned in 2008
```

Our web server is very outdated and I have been pushing for an upgrade to a modern Java Application Server and Java 1.6, but IT and the powers above me have yet to see a need for one.

But then I got an email that they found a security vulnerability (hot topic at work) with the web server

```
SunOne 6.1, SP9
```

And that it's patch required upgrading to a newer version of Java.  A few weeks later, a followup email stating the SunOne Patch was no longer required because it did not apply to us and therefore they would no longer be upgrading JRE.

Well, the SunOne vulnerabilty may not apply to us but there has to be some vulnerability with Java 1.4.2 that I can point out and leverage my new Application Server with !! :)

Comment: Ideally, every server everywhere should be kept up-to-date with recent patches and versions. There should be a good testing process in place to detect problems with these updates before they go-live. That's often just not possible in reality. If this is an "internal intranet web server", what impact would the security vulnerability have if it were exploited? Would the company lose data? Lose time? Expose itself to legal penalties? Are there other layers of security that protect this server, such as good control over who gets accounts, real isolation, etc?

Comment: @Freiheit (+1): along with that I'd add: ideally, every update would increase security and reliability, maintain backwards compatibility and not introduce new bugs. ;)

Comment: @Freiheit.  Honestly I feel we are secure enough running this version on our internal network.  The applications are not mission critical and data is backed nightly.  Corporate issued a Secure Coding policy that I must follow, but IT get's to say 'ahhh were secure without upgrading'.  I'm just frustrated coding on an outdated platform, I want JSF 2.0! Recoding to eliminate my secure coding deficiencies is painful. I was after some leverage to get a modern platform that I have been asking for for 5 years.

Comment: Good info @jeff. You might want to search over at programmers.stackexchange . There are lots of questions over there about how to sell a version change that will make your coders do better work and faster.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to convince the Powers That Be to upgrade a server.

1. Show that the existing will result in financial loss.
2. Show that you need the new features for a requested application.

To be frank, the first one is a tough road if you are not directly responsible for the health and maintenance of the server(s) in question.  Some may see the reasoning for your request as encroachment on their territory and point to a history of solid defense against hackers.  Of course, you *might* bring up Sony's recent issues in this regard.. at your own peril.  Heck, I've been at places where it took over a year to get service packs installed on some IIS boxes.  I was even shown the door at one place where I proved the existing router setup meant I could easily grab everyone's email passwords.

The second one is easier from a developer perspective.  Is there something in the latest JDK that you actually need?  For example, something that an app requirement can only be met through the use of the new feature?  If there isn't, then forget about it.  If there is, then your manager will make the case to provision a new server for your stuff.

The following is advice based on pure opinion.

From an Ethical Coder perspective, if you have security concerns, speak directly (not email) with the person(s) responsible and then move on.  The only time to take it further is if in your opinion the security issue may lead to loss of health, financial or other critical PII data.  At which point it would be expected for you to send an email with the proper CC's to those responsible as well as management.  However, once done let it go because it is completely out of your hands.  This will have fullfilled any requirement for warning and in the event of data loss you can be sure the appropriate legal authorities will be investigating that email trail.

The reason why I make a distinction is that the first path allows the person responsible to get over someone else pointing out that they aren't doing their job and decide how to proceed.  The second one is important to protect yourself in the event a serious issue occurs.

Bear in mind that regular IT has several concerns.  First, that version of the JDK is currently functional.  The apps based on it are functional.  IT (in general) has been bitch slapped way too many times for upgrading things simply because an update is available; due to this reason alone they may fight any changes.  Change and IT don't really go well together and this is a good thing from a broader company perspective.

Second, IT is responsible for security.  However, they have a lot of tools at their disposal.  From firewalls, to activity monitoring, to event log shipping, etc.  Before executing a change like this they need to know the issues with the new version (they always exist) as well as know whether they haven't already accounted for the issue you have brought attention to.  In other words, they may already be accounting for that issue in the JDK.  Also, they may already know the issues in the new JDK and not be able to plug those quite yet...

Which brings me to my last piece of advice.  Ignore the JDK security issues and focus on your job.  If you genuinely need the new version, I'm sure your manager can do what it takes to make it happen.  Advocating change especially in this way simply for a new version is in itself a non-starter.

---

Okay, last thing:

Imagine your dev manager (we'll call him bob) and the IT manager are in an ops meeting together with their boss.

The IT manager says, "jeff has been hounding us to upgrade servers x,y and z due to security concerns.  We looked at them but the issues are covered by our firewall.  Incidentally, how are those memory bug fixes coming?  We'd like to take decommission a couple boxes."

Bob: "We're hard at work on them.  I'll let jeff know."

Their boss: (thinking) 'Bob doesn't seem to have a handle on his team...They aren't focused on the task at hand and it's costing us real dollars.'

Now you are on your bosses *expletive* list.  Be careful or you will get burned.

Comment: Another "last thing".  I just read a previous question of yours (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904117/code-too-large-for-try-block).  Sounds to me like you have the exact situation necessary to upgrade that is a much better path than trying to convince them of a security vulnerability.  This should change the imagined conversation drastically.

Comment: Chris, I appreciate the great response. I felt if IT was required to upgrade JRE, they'd have to get a new app server since I think SunOne is not compatible with Java 6. I don't necessarily require something in a newer Java besides maybe VarArgs.

Comment: Chris, I don't necessarily have any security concerns using an older Java on our companies internal network. I just new SunOne 6.1 was not compatible with Java6 and therefore I could maybe get a newer app server for my internal utility apps that help fellow engineers do their job easier.

Comment: Chris, the scenario of your edit is not how it works at my company and especially in my department.  We are not a software development company.  My manager is responsible for issuing signed completed engineering drawings to build submarines.  I am an engineer in this department that just happened to write a workflow java app that helps coworkers follow a required six sigma procedure so we don't fail audits. So my manager and IT's manager have never met :)

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade.  See [HTTP Sun Java Calendar Deserialization Priv Escalation](http://www.symantec.com/business/security_response/attacksignatures/detail.jsp?asid=23392) which describes multiple buffer overflows and the floating point parsing DoS problems that affected far more recent versions.

Of relevance to someone running a Java server are

> 1. JRE creates temporary files in an insecure manner. Attackers can exploit this issue to write arbitrary JAR files and perform restricted actions on the affected computer. The issue is tracked in Sun Alert ID 244986 and CVE-2008-5360.
> 2. Multiple buffer-overflow vulnerabilities occur when JRE handles GIF images (CR 6766136) and processes fonts (CRs 6733336 and 6751322). The issues stem from heap overflows in the AWT library and may allow attacker to execute arbitrary code. The issues occur when a custom image model is used for the source 'Raster' during a conversion through a 'ConvolveOp' operation. These issues are tracked in Sun Alert ID 244987, CVE-2008-5356, CVE-2008-5357, CVE-2008-5358, and CVE-2008-5359.
> 3. A security-bypass weakness is present because the 'Java Update' mechanism of JRE fails to check digital signatures before installing them. This may allow attackers to install a malicious file on the affected computer by performing DNS-spoofing attacks. The issue is tracked in Sun Alert ID 244989 and CVE-2008-5355.
> 4. A security vulnerability in JRE may allow an untrusted applet or application to elevate privileges to the privileges of the user running the malicious application. The issue presents itself when deserializing the 'sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo' calendar object. An attacker can get ZoneInfo object deserialized in a privilege context by deserializing a calendar. The issue is tracked in Sun Alert ID 244991 and CVE-2008-5353.
> 5. A weakness in the JRE UTF-8 (Unicode Transformation Format-8) decoder occurs because it accepts encodings that are longer than the 'shortest' form. Attackers may exploit this issue to trick applications using the decoder into accepting invalid input. The issue is tracked in Sun Alert ID 245246 and CVE-2008-5351.
> 6. A denial-of-service vulnerability occurs because JRE improperly handles certain RSA public keys provided by remote clients of Java applications. The issue is tracked in Sun Alert ID 246286 and CVE-2008-5349.
> 7. A denial-of-service vulnerability occurs because of the way JRE authenticates users through Kerberos. Attackers may exploit this to exhaust operating system resources and deny service to legitimate users. The issue is tracked in Sun Alert ID 246346 and CVE-2008-5348.
> 8. Multiple security vulnerabilities in the JAX-WS and JAXB packages in JRE may allow untrusted applets to perform actions with elevated privileges. These issues are tracked in Sun Alert ID 246366 and CVE-2008-5347.
> 9. A security-bypass vulnerability occurs because code loaded from the local filesystem is allowed to access localhost. This may be used in attacks violating the same-origin policy. The issue is tracked in Sun Alert ID 246387 and CVE-2008-5345.

Comment: As Stephen pointed out, does this pertain to the RedHat version we have installed?

Answer (score 0):

Take your pick: http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-5/product_id-1083/version_id-74361/SUN-JDK-1.4.2.html

Comment: `java version "1.4.2", gij (GNU libgcj)` is not the SUN JDK

Comment: @Stephen, This is what I was wondering.  Our webserver is Sun SunONE.  But 'java --version' produces java version "1.4.2" gij (GNU libgcj) version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51). Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=java

Select the vulnerability that applies to your specific environment

Comment: thanks but how do I get the specifics for Java Red Hat 4.1.2-51? I don't think I can just email IT that link. I did http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=java+Red+Hat+4.1.2-51 but results are still abiguous.